# Escape from the Hives

Tags: story-identification, books

This book may go back as far as the '60s.

The story was about how all the general populace lived in 'hives' and the world was run by an elite that decided everything with no consultation. The peons were given a living stipend to stay home and indulge in hobbies of their choice - and they weren't to leave the properties they lived on.
The story was of one fellow's escape.

I did check the answers to a similar question, but no luck, maybe because the other question posited a dystopian condition, and this wasn't really.  They had everything they needed - except freedom.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did he escape _to_?  Do you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/50047751-the-price-of-paradise

Comment: Megan Terry's '[Home](https://www.concordtheatricals.com/s/8950/megan-terrys-home-or-future-soap)' (1967) fits this description quite nicely, but was a play rather than a book. Possibly you read a script?

Answer (score 6):

Like DavidW I think that the answer to this question is a novel by [T.J. Bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._J._Bass) (a pseudonym for Thomas J. Bassler). But due to the extra details in the comments concerning the presence of a chess grandmaster, I think it refers to Bass' second (and final novel) "[The Godwhale](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1857)".

Just as in Bass' first novel, "Half Past Human", it is set in a far future where a population of trillions of humans live in "Hive" cities. An AI named "Earth Systems" provide the degenerated humans - the Nebish - with a simple protein diet and menial jobs. The Nebish have been bred to be short, weak and conformist and (for some unexplained reason) to have four toes on each foot.

*Half Past Human* took place in the Hive's vast subterranean network of shafts, tubes, and cubicles, following the intersecting lives of large class of characters. *The Godwhale*, on the other hand, takes place mostly in the ocean. The titular character is the Rorqual Maru, a lone cyborg whale-ship plankton harvester, bent on restoring life to the ravaged oceans.

The chess grandmaster, Ode, was appointed to be captain of the Rorqual Maru. During the voyage, the fishing nets bring up a "Benthic", their term for "a hominid - giant, naked, and primitive... two feet taller and a hundred pounds heavier than a Nebish", i.e. a standard homo sapiens. The human attacks the crew, including captain Ode who was thrown against a wall, suffering

> multiple fractures of the pelvis and lower extremities, as well as
> several undisplaced rib fractures and a linear skull fracture.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible you're thinking of the 1971 novel [*Half Past Human*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1823) by T.J. Bass.  I don't recall it very well, but one of the main characters is a Nebish (hive dweller) named Tinker.

The [summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_Past_Human) says:

> Human science has created the four-toed Nebish, a pallid, short-lived and highly programmable humanoid who has had the elements that do not facilitate an underground Hive existence (aggression, curiosity, etc.) bred out of it.

Comment: was there a larger version of humans in this story? and a character who was a chess grandmaster?

Comment: Yes to the former, the was a remnant of original stock humans on the surface.  I don't remember anything about chess, but it's been 30 years.

Comment: There was a chess grandmaster (Grandmaster Ode) in the sequel "The Godwhale"

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez: Oh my gosh, that name rings a bell, thank!. IIRC, a ship full of the little creatures was attacked by a single big human and I think the grandmaster was injured or killed in this attack?